# Writing generic floating point code without a lot of boilerplate type constraints

Tags: generics, floating-point, rust

Is there a way to specify that the generic type `T` can only be either `f32` or `f64`? Otherwise I end up imposing a lot of boilerplate type constraints: `Copy`, `Add<Output=T>`, `Sub<Output=T>`, `Mul`..., `Div`..., `Zero`, `One`, etc., which gets tedious after a while. Also I am afraid this list will grow to include `Sin`, `Cos`, `Tan`, etc. in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`num::traits::Float`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/num/num/traits/trait.Float.html), available in crate `num`.

Every type satisfying `Float` is guaranteed to be `Num + Copy + NumCast + PartialOrd + Neg<Output=Self>`. In turn, `PartialEq + Zero + One + Add + Sub + Mul + Div + Rem` are required for `Num`. This answer your first requests for basic arithmetic. Other operations like `sin()`, `cos()` are available as member functions in `Float`.

Finally, `f32` and `f64` are supplied out-of-the-box as implementors of `Float`.

Comment: Trait `Float` is in the `num` crate at crates.io but not in `std::num`. Should I prefer the crates.io libraries over the `std::` libraries when they have the same name?

Comment: You don't have to compare them -- they are not the same thing. Use crate `num` for this.

Comment: There seems to still be an issue with this. When I call `std::iter::Iterator::sum` Rust complains that `core::num::Zero` is not implemented by type `T: num::Float`.

Comment: Ouch, that's unfortunate. This is because `num::traits::Float` implements `num::traits::Zero`, not `std::num::Zero`. You can fall back on `Iterator::fold` with the addition operation and 0 for `init`.

Comment: The link at the top of this answer is broken.  Anyone looking for the num crate can find it at https://crates.io/crates/num